# Check_MK, read-only OMD access for Digital Signage

Tags: nagios, check-mk

I have the latest version (1.4.0p34) of Check_MK setup on Ubuntu server 18 with LDAP integration. 
I would like to have a page displayed on a Digital signage that I have that is a slide show of an array of web pages.
Would someone here help me with an idea of how to get an exception for a particular MAC or IP address to display status page without login?
 I have done a bit of Internet searching and document review on the application site but have not found anything relevant to this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: why you ask this not at the check_mk Mailinglist https://mathias-kettner.de/check_mk_lists.html ? You can use the automation login https://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_multisite_automation.html regards

Comment: Because I prefer forums to mail lists. Thanks though for taking time to suggest.